# insert into database table from keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, key-value

Trying to match up a value in a list with the key in a keyvaluepair and retrieve the corresponding value from the keyvaluepair and use as sql parameter and in my example it is @ValueDE.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int,string> kvp in Valuedescripts)
{
    int val = kvp.Key;
    string descrip = kvp.Value;

    foreach (DataUds data in DataUds)
    {
        using (DB2Connection sqlconn = new DB2Connection())
        {
            sqlconn.Open();

            DB2Command cmdtx = new DB2Command();

            string insert = @"INSERT into LNPY (LN_NR, ITEM_NAME, MR_NR, VALUE)
                            VALUES (@LN, @Nbr, @Val, @ValueDE)";
            cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@Nbr", data.MN);
            cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@Ln", data.LN);
            cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@Val",data.item);
```

How do I get this parameter?
                 Cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@valueDE", ????

Data.item comes from a list and I need to use this value set it equal to val (kvp.key) and retrieve the corresponding Descrip and fill that in as parameter

Comment: So what is the problem? Why not use `int val` value?

Comment: I need to look up data.ln  In the keyvaluepair list and find the value that corresponds to the key and set that as the @valueDe parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to what you are exactly after except the point that you need value from keyvaluepair to be used as a parameter in your insert query. You're close I guess.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int,string> kvp in Valuedescripts)
{
    int val = kvp.Key;
    string descrip = kvp.Value;

    foreach (DataUds data in DataUds)
    {
        //something like
        if (descrip == data.item) //only u know it
        {
            using (DB2Connection sqlconn = new DB2Connection())
            {
                sqlconn.Open();

                DB2Command cmdtx = new DB2Command();

                string insert = @"INSERT into LNPY (LN_NR, ITEM_NAME, MR_NR, VALUE)
                                  VALUES (@LN, @Nbr, @Val, @ValueDE)";
                cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@Nbr", data.MN);
                cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@Ln", data.LN);
                cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@Val",data.item);
                cmdtx.Parameters.Add("@ValueDE", val);
             }

             break; //again only u know it. Will be good if you have only item to match
        }  
    }
}
```

Furthermore do not insert a list of objects to db this way which will be much slower than bulk insert using `VALUES (...), (....), (......` syntax. You should loop thru the foreachs to construct the query actually..

Comment: Alright more explanation data.item comes from a list and I need to use that value to lookup a val(kvp.key) in the keyvaluepair list and if the data.item=val (kvp.key) I want to retrieve descrip(kvP.value) and fill in parameter.

Comment: Sorry I missed the if at the top.

Comment: @LewSim if you need to check data.item value with a value in list of keyvaluepairs then your outer loop should better be the datauds loop and inner loop be list of keyvaluepair loop